# Hibernate, Spring @ResponseBody String causes the object can not be validated

Tags: java, ajax, spring, hibernate, validation

I'm doing validation for the phoneNumber attribute and trying to force the user to type in numeric only. But for some reasons if i set the method return type to an object type it works perfectly, but when i set it to a String type my object can not be validated. The console doesn't give any messages, and the ajax call return a perfectly normal message.

view :

```
<div id ="EditModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <form class="modal-dialog" th:action="@{/EditPhoneNumber}" th:object="${phoneNumber}" method="POST" id="PhoneEditForm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="edit-modal-phone-number-id" name="id" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number" id="edit-modal-phone-number-number" name="number" value=""/>
                    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="edit-modal-person-id" name="personID" th:value="${personID}"/>
                    <p id="EditFormError"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="SubmitEdit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ValidateEditPhoneNumber",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String ValidatePhoneNumber(@Validated @RequestBody PhoneNumberRequest phoneNumber, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "Something happened";
        }
        else return "SUCCESS";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/EditPhoneNumber", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editPerson(@ModelAttribute(value="phoneNumber") PhoneNumberRequest phone) {
        personService.updatePhoneNumber(phone.getId(), phone.getNumber());
        return "redirect:All";
    }
```

ajax function :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#SubmitEdit").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("it ran here");
                var inputID = $("#edit-modal-phone-number-id").val();
                var inputNumber = $("#edit-modal-phone-number-number").val();
                var inputPersonID = $("#edit-modal-person-id").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "/ValidateEditPhoneNumber",
                    dataType : "text",
                    data : JSON.stringify({"id" : inputID, "number" : inputNumber, "personID" : inputPersonID}),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success : function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#PhoneEditForm").submit();
                    },
                    error : function(result){
                        alert("Error "+result.responseText);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

my entity :

```
@NotNull
private long id;

@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9])")
private String number;

@NotNull
private long personID;

//getter,setter
```

Comment: What do you get in console for `result`? And I think the `dataType` should be `text/plain` instead of just `text`.

Comment: I always use `json` as `dataType`

Comment: i get the "SUCCESS" string from controller normally. Everything run normally except the object isnt validated